# UITableView disappears when i set constraints with Size Classes and Auto layout

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I don't understand why my tableview don't appear when a set width/height constraints !
Can somebody help me ?

Thanks

Comment: please post some code or specify more what you are doing precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that with Auto-Layout you need to set several constraints.  First I'd test it in the Interface Builder (set the constraints, then update the frames and see if it moves).

I have found that I normally need to set constraints that both control size and position or I will get effects I didn't expect.  For example, you can set height, width, and pin it somewhere (IE set the left boarder and top edge to something that is defined).

Or you can set all 4 boarders to something that is defined (IE the edge of the screen) which will control both size and location.  Don't just set size though, set location to via a constraint (Pin it to something!)